# What is the cardinality in this situation?

Tags: oracle-12c, cardinality-estimates

I need to find the cardinality for a few tables in an Oracle database. I have been given a word document that has a list of tables described with details as shown in the image:

[image]

I have been reading about cardinality.  As far as I understand, cardinality can be used to describe the relationship between two tables.
I have gone over this question and its answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621077/what-is-cardinality-in-databases

but I still lack the understanding on how to move on in solving my problem.

I need help in determining what type of cardinality I need to find, and how to find it.

I have also gone over this content, but I am not sure if this is what I need to do.
https://www.mysqldba.co.uk/articles/2008/02/26/how-to-calculate-cardinality

I need to find the cardinality for columns col5, col6, and col7.